# Why does Safari render this Open Sans text in this way?

Tags: fonts, safari, text-rendering

This text says "mathematical biology":

[image: mathematical biology]

I'm using Safari 9.0.2 (11601.3.9) and OS 10.11.2

Comment: Downvote: more information about the scenario

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor, what other information would be useful? The browser, os, font name, and image of the rendering is all I can think of. It's such a strange behavior that I'd expect the image is quite diagnostic of the issue.

Comment: What is the font name?

Comment: Open Sans (in the title)

Answer (score 0):

"Try restoring the system fonts using the Font Book.app

Open and click Restore Standard fonts"

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/129713